# ios 6 : issue - Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation

Tags: iphone, ios

I am getting an error when I started running the app and after that the application is not touchable or reponding

```
Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation.
```

My iPhone application supports only the portrait mode.

Comment: what are you exactly  want to do ?

Comment: I want to know why this error is getting and also how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had this problem and fixed it by moving the assignment for the window's rootViewController past the adding of view controllers to the tabBarController. Not sure why that particular error was generated or if that fits your code.